# nagios adding extra link to service as meta information user can click

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I am using Nagios to monitor some services, and would like to provide an external link on the web interface so that when a service does down, the operator can click on it and be redirected to an other server providing incident ticketing.

I have tried with the 'notes_url' keyword with no much success, the redirection is done on the same domain than the one hosting nagios, even if using absolute urls as indicated by the documentation. There is also the action_url, which is not even shown!

I remember having seen somewhere that an icon user can click on it can be created; but I can't find how to do this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `action_url` - However, this will be a permanent link no matter the state.

(Sorry, best I can do! Not sure how you can only display if down).

Comment: No, thanks fine :) I would like to provide a permanent link, when up, to the ticketing server with, like, older incidents on this service. The problem is even with absolute urls (http://www....) the link is to the nagios server (http://nagios.mydomain.net/nagios3/www....)

Comment: @philippe - make sure to add http:// - this works fine on my Nagios ... Not sure the difference between notes_url and action_url though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of searching for a second option, the simple solution should be configuring the notes_url itself...
Lets find out how to resolve this notes_url...what happened with this notes_url??  could you tell us exactly what happened with the notes_url??

thanks,